# Fetch Update precondition failed

Tags: google-drive-api

One week ago, Fetch method of Google.Apis.v2.DriveService.Files.Update throw exception 412 Precondition failed.

I had realize previous operation getting file using DocID. Later, I update this file without changes then I get this error message.

```
Errors [
    Message[Precondition Failed] Location[If-Match - header] Reason[conditionNotMet] Domain[global] ]
```

Could you help me?

Comment: This is a known bug, we're working on it.